# Displaying many pictures on an android app - OutofMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I'm trying to load a bunch of pictures associated with groups on my app. I use a recyclerview to show the group cardview's, but each cardview is supposed to show an associated thumbnail.

The pictures, I guess, are too large to be stored in memory because when the activity loads it gets an OutOfMemoryException right away.

How can you display images on an android app without having to store them in memory first?

As of right now, I am loading all of the images right off the bat - definitely the source of the problem.  I've read mention of "lazy loading" and I'm familiar with the concept from working with Ruby on Rails, but how can this be accomplished with bitmaps on android?

Comment: Have you at least read this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Also this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Actually, you should probably go ahead and just read the entire training module on working with bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Just use a third party library  ex: http://square.github.io/picasso/